# How to simplify cells selection in visual basic for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a small program for Excel using Visual Basic. When I click one of the cells L12 to U12, it change the color of another one. This is what I have at the moment:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Sheets("sheet1")

        .Range("A1:K11").Interior.Color = RGB(40, 40, 250)
        .Range("B2:J10").Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)

        Select Case Target.Address

            Case "$L$12", "$M$12", "$N$12", "$O$12", "$P$12", "$Q$12", "$R$12", "$S$12", "$T$12", "$U$12"
                .Range("B2").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

        End Select

    End With

End Sub
```

I want to know if it is possible to shorten the Case line like :

```
Case "$L$12" : "$U$12"
```

or something like this.
I have a few more Case to do and wanted to know if there was a smart way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: `If Target.Row = 12 And Target.Column >= 12 And Target.Column <= 21 Then .Range("B2").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)` instead of the `Select Case...`?

Comment: Working fine but I prefer the solution below. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use code below:

```
If Not Intersect(Range("L12:U12"), Target) Is Nothing then
    .Range("B2").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End If
```